# ShutdownNow on ExecutorService does not work properly

Tags: java, spring

I'm wiriting a Spring Boot app for simulating an events generator of syslog. With a rest call I have to start the events generation and with another rest call I have to stop it. To achieve that, I created an ExecutorService with a single thread with a for loop inside the Runnable, but it does not stop at all. I tried to break the for loop with Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted after the shutdownNow() but it seems that it does not set the IsInterrupted to true. If I use the loop boolean, of course the loop stop but I can't create new thread with a 500 server error.

That's my code:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class EventService {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventService.class);
    private ConfigReader configReader;

    private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    
    private EventsGenerator eventsGen;
    
    private String test;

    public EventService(ConfigReader configReader) {
        this.configReader = configReader;
    }

    public void init(byte[] fileConfig) throws IOException {

        configReader.read(fileConfig);

        eventsGen = new EventsGenerator(configReader,configReader.getConfig().getProtocol());

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                eventsGen.stop();
                try {
                    executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        executor.execute(eventsGen);

        executor.shutdown();


        /*      
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

         */

    }
    
    public void shutdownService() {
        eventsGen.stop();
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Run method of eventsGenerator:

```
    @Override
        public void run() {
    
        //other things
            int it;
            for(i=0;i<max;i++) {
                try {
                    
                    if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        break;
                    }

                    if(!loop){
                      break;
                      }
                    
                    NStringTemplate template = getNextTemplate();
                    String message = template.buildString(context);
                    if(config.getEndTime() != null) {
                        Date currentTime = context.getTime(false);
                        if(currentTime.after(config.getEndTime())) {
                            logger.info("L'endTime è stato superato");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
           //other business logic
        }catch(Exception exc){}
        }

public void stop(){
setLoop(false);
}
```

Comment: Do not stop here meaning that the `logger.info("L'endTime è stato superato");` always print out?

Comment: Setting `loop` should do it (`shutdownNow()` does not set `interrupted` to the thread). Not sure why there should be a 500 error on subsequent calls.

Comment: Setting loop to false did the trick of course, but after another call of the init method (invoked by the rest call) the server gives 500. By the stacktrace printed on console seems to be a ThreadPool problem, I suppose because the first thread still exists and I can't create another thread.

@kidnan1991 nope, the message is for another logic, it's the for loop that does not break out